# Graceful exit for multithreaded haskell

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

This is entirely theoretical at this point, but I've been trying to wrap my
head around this problem. Let's take a client for an example.  There are
forkIOd threads for every connection, and one of them wants to quit the
entire program (ie. /exit).  How would this information be propagated to
other threads?

This is not a condition, but I assume that the threads are reading from
their respective threads which are blocking. Since they're idling away
until something is written for them, they can't poll any kind of "done"
variable. So my first thought `unless done` is bunked.

I don't have a solution in mind for any program, so anyone giving solutions
for any language is appreciated, but the real question is how to do it in
Haskell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way I know of is poison, which is implemented by the CHP library.

See the excellent explanation here: http://chplib.wordpress.com/2009/09/30/poison-concurrent-termination/

The above article incidentally goes through other solutions and explains why they're generally somewhat fragile.